# How to use Minio Client with a Minio server in Arch?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I want to be able to use the Minio client in arch

I use Arch with Minio version

```
$ minio version 
Version: DEVELOPMENT.GOGET
Release-Tag: DEVELOPMENT.GOGET
Commit-ID: DEVELOPMENT.GOGET
```

and Minio client version

```
$ mcli version 
Version: 2018-03-23T17:45:52Z
Release-tag: DEVELOPMENT.2018-03-23T17-45-52Z
Commit-id: fe82b0381c5ccf004515be3bfd9b6fa733890005
```

when I want to add the config file I get as shown when starting the minio server

```
$ mcli config host add myminio <YOUR-S3-ENDPOINT> <YOUR-ACCESS-KEY> <YOUR-SECRET-KEY>
mcli: Configuration written to `/home/user/.mc/config.json`. Please update your access credentials.
mcli: Successfully created `/home/user/.mc/share`.
mcli: Initialized share uploads `/home/user/.mc/share/uploads.json` file.
mcli: Initialized share downloads `/home/user/.mc/share/downloads.json` file.
mcli: <ERROR> Unable to initialize new config from the provided credentials The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method
```

on the server I get the print out

```
ERRO[0529] \{
    "method": "GET",
    "reqURI": "/probe-bucket-sign/?location=",
    "header": {
        "Authorization": ["AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<Creadentisl>/20180323/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=<signature>"],
        "Host": ["<YOUR-S3-ENDPOINT>"],
        "User-Agent": ["Minio (linux; amd64) minio-go/5.0.1"],
        "X-Amz-Content-Sha256": ["<...>"],
        "X-Amz-Date": ["20180323T174913Z"]
    }   
} 
cause=Signature does not match source=[auth-handler.go:122:checkRequestAuthType()]
```